# Power layer filled with many different voltages

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers

I have a board with 4 layrs: signal, GND, power, signal. I have a couple different voltages starting from a USB charger input until the very end to a BLE module:

- Input before current measurement header
- Input after current measurement header
- Battery voltage (out of the charger IC)
- System voltage (out of the charger IC)
- 3.3V before current m. header
- 3.3V after current m. header
- 3.3V I can separately turn off for a sensor

(I have 2 pin headers interrupting the power path for current measurement. When I'm done with playing it there are two solder bridges I solder closed to bypass the headers.) So on the 3rd layer there are many different filled areas for all these separated voltage-areas. One of them got place on the bottom layer.

[image: Power layer]

My question is: is this how it's done, is this unacceptable or what? Can somebody with experience comment and say a few words please! It would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Edit:
Two more screenshots just to explain why I'm doing this:
Here VBAT is connected with nets. I can't remember seeing anything like this ever on a board. This look just terrible to me:
[image: VBAT with net]

This is the same thing using a filled polygon:

[image]

This was the part dealing with the battery voltage. But this is around a charge controller, so there is an input voltage polygon (actually 2, before and after current measurement), and a VSYS output as well.

So on the next picture VBAT is the filled area on the top, bottom left is VIN before current measurement, bottom right is VIN after current measurement.

The battery voltage's case is pretty simple, but the VIN is connected to 5/20 pins of the controller on 3 different sides, so routing traces gets chaotic there pretty quick.

Is this really bad?

[image]

Comment: This is not best practice, but without knowing more details of your board I can't say whether it's unacceptable or not. The component placement looks worryingly haphazard, though.

Comment: Can you place all components closer together? Can you sort them by supply and group them accordingly?

Comment: @winny, they are together sorted by supply! This is what allows me to put them over a filled area with their specific power. And closer together? I thought they were already close. I feel sorry for the robot placing these parts... :)

Comment: @Hearth, is it haphazard because of that un-routed component or generally? The un-routed component is a switch that turns on a voltage divider to measure input voltage. Unfortunately it measures the very first voltage and it's turned on/off by the very last device. Tell me what more info you need to help me out more - if you would do that.

Comment: @GambanishuHabbeba No, the unrouted components just make it look unfinished, nothing wrong with that. What I meant by haphazard placement is just how things seem to have unnecessarily long traces between them, how spaced out everything is; I don't know what this board is doing so maybe that's fine, but it doesn't feel like good practice to me.  It'll certainly make your board cost a little more to manufacture (smaller boards are cheaper).

Comment: Unless the courtyards are touching, they are far apart. If there is significant height difference, your EMS may complain as the courtyard does not tell you everything.